# C++ char array scope

Tags: c++, arrays, scope, stack, char

```
char* pArray = nullptr;
{
    char buffer[64];
    sprintf_s(buffer,"Time: 123456");
    pArray = buffer;

}
cout<<pArray<<endl;
```

"Time: 123456" is displayed even though the buffer has been deallocated back to the stack. What is going on here? Is this safe? Not safe?

Comment: No, it is not safe. Its `undefined behavior`.

Comment: There are maybe another 20 or 30 posts here on SO asking the same question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **undefined behavior**. The memory probably isn't cleared.

It's pure luck your print statement works. When an object goes out of scope or is deleted, the memory is marked as released and not actually erased. The program can reclaim it and overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the memory anymore, but the data is still there.

You should not do stuff like that unless you know what you're doing.

You can use a hack like that to pass some parameters to a function but it's very unsafe.